# Exception Win32Exception: No application is associated even if it is associated

Tags: c#, file, pdf, printing, associations

I have C# program, which sends uses PrintTo verb when spawning process to print file to specified printer. However, when I try to print .pdf or html file, it says

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

I have PDF Complete installed and double clicking on pdf file opens it correctly. Same things happens with .html file (I have Mozilla Firefox as default browser).

#### EDIT:

My code:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(args[0]);
info.Arguments = "\"" + args[1] + "\"";
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.Verb = "PrintTo";
Process.Start(info);
```

And command line call: `>myapp.exe D:\Temp\test.pdf "PDF Complete"`

For example `>myapp.exe D:\Temp\test.txt "PDF Complete"` works

Comment: Then maybe startInfo is wrong?

Comment: @VladL I added code as well as information, how am I calling the application.

Comment: What about launching from command prompt just the file... ie cd D:\Temp and then D:\Temp\test.pdf (enter)- does this launch the pdf correctly?

Comment: Is D:\Temp\test.pdf a real path or maybe the real one has whitespaces?

Comment: @alykins Yes, there is no problem doing that. It opens in PDF Complete. `start test.pdf` also works.

Comment: @VladL As I added to question, calling it with txt file works, so I assumme path is correct.

Comment: Sure `start test.pdf` will work if you call it from command line, but if you pass it to the application, then args[0] will contain `start` and args[1] `test.pdf`

Comment: I know, but I am passing just `D:\Temp\test.pdf`, as is shown in question.

Comment: Does "PDF Complete" support the `PrintTo` verb? Your `start` command is testing it with the `Open` verb. If you run your program with `Open` (or `Print`, etc.) instead of `PrintTo`, does it work?

Comment: @abarnert That's a good question. How can I check that?

Comment: @Zereges: Well, the second half is obvious: change `PrintTo` to `Open` in your code. For the first half… I don't remember the detail, but I do remember that both PowerShell and Windows Scripting Host have a way to open a file with an arbitrary verb, even if cmd/start doesn't.

Comment: You were right. PDF Complete does not support PrintTo verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone still interested. PrintTo verbs are not quite supported by neither PDF Complete nor Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on a method that was printing a .pdf.  Everything worked great until my computer crashed due to an array failure on the hdd controller.

After I rebuilt the computer I went back to finishing this code portion. However, it didn't work - I got the error listed in the OP above.

After a bit of inspection and checking out this thread I discovered that Windows 10 was using Edge for .pdf files. I installed Adobe Reader and viola~!  No more error and the Process.Start() printed the file.